# Playing a sound in a game using import os Python

Tags: python, operating-system, media

```
if bulletstate == "fire": 
    os.system("afplay Missile+2.wav&")
    y = bullet.ycor()
    y += bulletspeed
    bullet.sety(y)
```

This is a small section of my code that works for mac using the import os module. I am focusing on the os.system("afplay Missile+2.wav&) line.
What I want to know is how do I change this to make it work for windows while still using import os so that when the sound is played it does not crash my game when it is played.

Comment: This is not a python question. You are just running a system command. It is the same as typing `afplay Missile+2.wav&` in the console. I'm not sure what would be the equivalent on Windows, but maybe `explorer Missile+2.wav&`...

Comment: Since you're using a *very* Linux-specific mechanism (not just specific to Linux in general, but even specific to a single one of the several sound frameworks on Linux), you'll need to make larger changes than you want to make things portable -- ideally, using a cross-platform sound library for Python.

Comment: @zvone, I don't think `&` puts things in the background in the Windows shell. At least, not as far as I know. *shrug*